# Facebook Graph API - access_token=app_id|app_secret - search Graph API without user login

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I see that facebook require now to have access_token for searching users.
I'm folowwing these links:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

[User access token for search via facebook graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792760/user-access-token-for-search-via-facebook-graph?rq=1)

They are saying the same, that I can use "&access_token=app_id|app_secret" for querying the Graph API,
I still get an error
"error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }

I need to search facebook users from my web site, I don't need user of my web site to login to facebook.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)

`The following changes will go into effect on July 10, 2013:`
.....

```
Graph API search changes
App access tokens will be required for all search Graph API calls except Places and Pages. Search for application will no longer be supported.
```

Comment: That's my point, so they provide &access_token=app_id|app_secret to get an access token, It's not working for me

Comment: No, they don't. It's no longer supported.